# Query to output max movie tickets for each genre

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out the customer that has watched the highest number of movies for each genre. The query would output customerId as well as movieGenre that they have watched the most out of all customers on record. If a movieGenre has not been watched by anyone, that would be ignored from the output. If customers are tied for a movieGenre, all of the tied customers will be outputted.

Below is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE customers ( 
    customerId      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    customerName    VARCHAR(20),
    city            CHAR(20)     
);

CREATE TABLE movies (  
    movieId         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    movieGenre      VARCHAR(20),
    moviePrice      NUMERIC(10,2)
);

CREATE TABLE tickets (    
    ticketId      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ticketDate    DATE,        
    customerId    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES customers
);

CREATE TABLE details (    
    ticketId            INTEGER REFERENCES tickets,  
    movieId             INTEGER REFERENCES movies, 
    numOfTickets        SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticketId, movieId)
);

CREATE TABLE transactions (   
    transactionId       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ticketId            INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES tickets,
    transactionAmount   NUMERIC(8,2)    
);

CREATE TABLE Payments (   
    paymentId       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    paymentAmount   NUMERIC(8,2) CHECK ( amount > 0 ),
    transactionId   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES transactions
);
```

This is my query:

```
select m.movieGenre, max(c.customerId) 
from movies m join details d 
    on m.movieId = d.movieId join tickets t 
    on d.ticketId = t.ticketId join customers c 
    on t.customerId < c.customerId 
group by m.movieGenre;
```

My query outputs 96 for all movie genres which is incorrect. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the customer/genre count for all pairs in the data.  I think this is:

```
select m.movieGenre, t.customerId, count(*)
from movies m join
     details d 
     on m.movieId = d.movieId join
     tickets t 
     on d.ticketId = t.ticketId 
group by m.movieGenre, t.customerId;
```

Then to get the max for each group, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (m.movieGenre) m.movieGenre, t.customerId, count(*)
from movies m join
     details d 
     on m.movieId = d.movieId join
     tickets t 
     on d.ticketId = t.ticketId 
group by m.movieGenre, t.customerId
order by m.movieGenre, count(*) desc;
```

Comment: The answer I get is closer to the actual values now, but they're still off by a bit. Action is supposed to be 74, I get 69 with this query. Same with some of the other genres.

Comment: @Sam . . . Perhaps the other data is summing the number of tickets.

Comment: Could you explain again? I don't think ticketDate is used for any queries so I doubt that's causing any errors in the query

Comment: @Sam . . . My comment was referring to `numOfTickets`.